# Statistical test to compare plant growth under different conditions

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, growth-model

I conducted an experiment where I measured *A. cepa* growth over time under different conditions. I aimed to determine to what extent caffeine concentration affected growth *over time*.

I have 8 data sets, one for each caffeine level (0 - 700 mg) over a period of 1 week. (7 points per data set.) What test should I use? I've considered using regression, but I'm not sure how I would be able to implement the *over time* aspect. I think that the test(s) should be able to give specific conclusions regarding:

- whether there is a statistically significant difference in growth patterns between the different conditions. This is perhaps the most important.
- an equation modeling growth (I feel like regression should work here, but I'm not sure how I'd do with with 3 dimensions--caffeine level, growth, and time)
- an equation modeling rate of growth (perhaps I could just take the derivative of the growth-equation, assuming that the growth equation isn't linear)

I apologize if this is a simple question; I haven't ever taken a statistics class in my life.

Comment: The first thing to do in almost any data analysis is to plot the data. You might find that an appropriate graph not only makes the patterns in the data clear, but it also makes the type of analysis that will best serve your purposes clear.

Comment: I would first plot the time-courses of the eight levels of treatment. I might also plot the dose-response curves at each time point, which would be the same 3-dimensional data 'sliced' along a different axis.

Comment: @MichaelLew understood everything except for _"plot the dose-response curves at each time point, which would be the same 3-dimensional data 'sliced' along a different axis"_. Is this a graph with 3 axes, or a means of graphing that allows the expression of three dimensions (caffeine level, growth, and time) on a two dimensional graph?

Comment: You are starting off with a fairly complex analysis given the fact you never had any statistics classes in your life. However, your three bullets are very good objectives given the experiment. It's tough to provide any advise without an exemplary dataset for people to work with or to illustrate various approaches. I would suggest having a look at **longitudinal data analysis** using a repeated measures ANOVA or linear mixed effects models approach.

Comment: @Princee You have caffeine level as dose (x-axis), growth as response (y-axis) and a curve for each time point. Another way to slice the data is time as x-axis, growth as y-axis and a curve for each dose of caffeine.

Comment: I think this question is well specified enough and interesting enough that a sufficiently skilled person should be able to give it an answer. I would love to hear it.